# How to tell if I'm going through a range expander

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I just installed a wireless range expander.  It seems the only way to get it to work is to give it the same channel and SSID as my router.  So how can I tell whether I'm going through the router or the range expander at any particular time?

Comment: can you please post make and model of the extender?

Comment: make and model of the extender: wre54g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a Linux machine with a wireless card that supports monitor mode to tell.

Configure it to the same channel in monitor mode, then run `tcpdump` or `wireshark` capturing on that interface.  You should see your laptop using the MAC address of the extender in one of the four 802.11 layer address fields (the AP MAC address will also appear, as will the BSSID of the network... the key thing is the extender's MAC showing up).

Comment: Can you explain "monitor mode"?

Answer (score 2):

The range expander is basically just repeating the same signals as the router. The expander doesn't have it's own IP at all. It will possibly give you slightly more latency, but is a fairly simple piece of equipment.

Comment: Are you sure?  I think it does have an IP, because you can contact it through a browser and configure it

Comment: From my understanding (which could be wrong) it has an IP, but that is used for configuration only. The actual traffic passing is merely a reflection.

Comment: yes, that IP address only used if you connect the extender to a computer to run the configuration utility.

Comment: So is there any way to tell what I'm connecting to?

Comment: I can't think of any way to tell, at least not through software.  I suppose that with appropriate RF test gear you'd be able to figure it out though.